# Objective-C assigning an long int to text label not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to assign a long int to text Label like so:

```
labelOne.text = [object objectForKey:@"TagId"];
```

[object objectForKey:@"TagId"]; is 1234567

but when I run my code, all my labels that were working before appear blank including labelOne.

What Am I doing wrong.

Comment: You have to use [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%i",[object objectForKey:@"TagId"]];

Comment: From where you tried to set the text ? Did you connect the outlet ?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati No, that is not right.

Comment: This is what the debugger is for. Confirm `labelOne` isn't `nil`. Confirm `object` isn't `nil`. Confirm that `object[@"TagId"]` isn't `nil`.

Comment: Yes, this label is working when I set it to `@"aaa"` it display aaa

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati I tried your solution and got this error `No known class method for selector 'StringWithFormat:'`

Comment: @LosaniHomes Don't try Muhammad's comment. It's completely wrong.

Comment: What is `object` and what type is `TagID`? Does `id tagID = [object objectForKey:@"TagId"]` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this.

```
NSString *tagId = [object objectForKey:@"TagId"];
labelOne.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",tagId?tagId:@""];
```

Comment: How does this help? All this does is change a possible `nil` value to the empty string. The end result is the same - the label will be blank.

Comment: and also check  the return value of '[object objectForKey:@"TagId"];' i think it return nil

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 labelOne.text = [[object objectForKey:@"TagId"]stringValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like to me is `[object objectForKey:@"TagId"]` returns reference object, not a primative type, long int.

If the object that is returned at `[object objectForKey:@"TagId"]` is NSNumber, then you'll have to use this:

```
[[object objectForKey:@"TagId"] integerValue]; //integerValue, longValue, unsignedIntegerValue, etc. look at the documentation for NSNumber to see which one will fit best for you
```

Then once you have your long int, you'd use the conversion to change it into a string:

```
NSString *text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", [[object objectForKey:@"TagId"] longValue]];
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

You should create an NSNumber, then you should assign that NSNumber's `stringValue` property to the label's text, like so:

```
NSNumber* tagID = [NSNumber numberWithLong:[object objectForKey:@"TagId"]];
labelOne.text = [tagID stringValue];
```

Comment: Why? The value is originally a string. How does all of this needless conversion help?

Comment: @rmaddy How do you know it's a string? In the title to the question the OP asks how to assign a long int to a label.

Comment: Because if it wasn't an `NSString`, then the line posted in the question would have crashed. And you can't store a raw `long int` in a dictionary. So it's either wrapped as a string or an `NSNumber`. But `NSNumber` would have crashed the posted line.

Comment: @rmaddy Well, I'm not 100% sure about the types of the variables, but I get the feeling that whatever is coming out of `objectForKey:` isn't an `NSString`.

Comment: As I said, if it isn't an `NSString`, the code in the question would crash. So either the line isn't being executed at all or it is an `NSString` (or `nil`).